# Azure image Content Moderator - it only responds with exact match images

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, power-automate

I have subscribed and built API calls (using Flow) to search images in my image list in Content Moderator. However, it seems it only return exact match image. Is there any parameter I can control the fuzzy match or even the degree of matching results?

Comment: No, there is no parameter to control the results.

Answer (score 1):

I am from the Content Moderator team. Looks like we missed responding to this question. Sorry for that!

We in fact do fuzzy matching, but with small thresholds. The algorithm can handle some cropping and color changes. So a slightly cropped image or an image with colors should match the original(uncropped) or a black and white version respectively.

There is no parameter to control the degree of matching.

Thanks!

Comment: I am using the image moderator on website and it looks like the adult images are classified as racy image